# How to play video in Atom editor?

Tags: html, atom-editor

Here is the content of my .atom/init.coffee file

```
View=require('atom').View
class Player extends View
  @content: -> @raw """
 <video  controls width="100%" height="100%" id="video">
      <source src="file:///C:/Users/myname/play/html5/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
"""
player=new Player
atom.workspaceView.appendToLeft(player)
```

After Atom editor launched,  the control bar of a HTML5 video displayed, but it can not play its specified video file.

How to play video in Atom editor?

Comment: I'd guess the underlying framework does not have video support compiled in, unlike Chrome browser. As, in the end, you need to pay MPEG  consortium licensing fees if you redistribute codecs (h264).

Comment: yes.I have managed to play webm files but it is not seekable and fullscreenable.

Comment: See: https://github.com/tyage/video-player

Comment: To play videos that require a mpeg codec, you will need the right codec.  On Linux, I got it working by copying the `libffmpegsumo.so` file from Chromium (*/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpegsumo.so*) to Atom's location (*/opt/atom/libffmpegsumo.so*).

Comment: Another package that displays a video player in a window pane: https://github.com/tong/atom-videoplayer